# SpyOn jquery selector function call jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, spy

I would like to spy on the `is(':focus')` function of a jQuery selector.

It looks as follows:

```
$('.some-input-class').is(':focus')
```

Some of my attempts are:

```
spyOn($('<div class="some-input-class">'), 'is').andReturnValue(false) ;

spyOn($('.some-input-class'), 'is').andReturnValue(false) ;

spyOn($, 'is').andReturnValue(false) ;
```

But none of them seems to be working. 
I always get undefined for the spyOn definition.